# Thunderbird is excruciatingly slow

Tags: windows-10, thunderbird

Thunderbird is excruciatingly slow - in ***every*** operation (I feel it most when compositing, but even just making my way through menus is sloooow).  It feels like low memory, but I have 18gB or more of free RAM in Windows 10, and nothing else is running slowly.

What could I do to speed it up, as I am seriously considering switching email client, but don't know of anything as good?

Comment: Is there some ongoing operation, e.g. antimalware scan? Some scanners are incompatible with some email clients. **Temporarily** turn off AV suite, and , if problem goes away, try a different brand.

Comment: Truning off Avast *seemed* to improve things slightly, but still not aceptable. Typing during compose and nothing seems to happen, then the text shows up after a delay .... (+1 though, for a good suggestion)

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica slowness while typing describes a known issue with early version 78.  You will want to update to 78.2.2 or higher (current version is 78.3.1).

Regarding Avast, it certainly can cause issues*. But you don't need to turn it off, you can exclude parts of Avast that are affecting Thunderbird.
* https://wiki.mozilla.org/Thunderbird:Testing:Antivirus_Related_Performance_Issues#AVAST

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. One week later and things seem better. If you post that as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Could be lots of things, including hardware.  Suggest you review https://wiki.mozilla.org/Thunderbird:Testing:Memory_Usage_Problems and post your results

Answer (score 0):

Open **Task Manager** (alt-ctrl-delete) and look at your processes. The culprit could be thunderbird or another program that is hogging all your disk usage, cpu, and/or RAM.

If that doesn't work, reinstall thunderbird.

Comment: Over 18gNB free RAM, CPU at ubder 50%, maybe 20% free disk space from 3tB. Reinstalling is a last resort, unless you can tell me how to save my config. Thanks for the advice, though :-)